# Output into new window

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pycharm, cloud9-ide

How am I able to print my output into a new window, I use the IDE **Cloud 9** or **PyCharm** and the output comes up on a window on the bottom. Is there a command to **print the output into a new window entirely**, either through Pycharm or just python itself? My OS is Windows and I have Googled this and haven't seen anything that helps.

Comment: Windows, sorry I didn't mention it

Comment: I just tried PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.3 on Windows 7 and the floating mode selection worked for me. You didn't mention which version of PyCharm you're using. Maybe you have an old version of PyCharm that doesn't allow this behavior?

Comment: Unfortunately cloud9 doesn't yet support moving your terminal to a new window. It's a feature I really want to see too and it's coming soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the console tab out of the bottom:

https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/splitting-and-unsplitting-editor-window.html

Right click the tab and select floating mode.

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: It half helped, the window is bigger but that was not my problem, I wanted to print it to a new window entirely

Comment: I believe if you drag the tab out somewhere not on the window, it should create a new window

Comment: Right click the tab and select floating mode.

Comment: It works not, I put in floating mode and stretched it but it is still a tab, and it doesn't let me drag it off screen for a new window

Comment: Hmm... I can't help you with that. I'm working on a mac and it is different on windows. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Try running something simple and silly, like this:

```
for i in range(10000):
    print i
```

I tried this in PyCharm Community edition 4.0.3 on Windows 7 and it worked for me. Go down to the bottom where it says "Run". In Community Edition anyway, it is NOT a tab, but a window, so you just need to right-click near where it says "Run". Then choose "Floating Mode". For me, it immediately popped into its own window and I could drag it outside the program.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but that is still within the program, I can't switch back and forth between the two, it is one on top of another